# How to Run PPTM macro from excel for Embedded PPTM file

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have an Excel file with a .PPTM embedded into a sheet (nothing else is on the sheet).  I want to run a macro that is in the PPTM file.
The problem is the last line of code to run the macro.   The cell in worksheet "PPTM" that has the embedded file has a formula of "=EMBED("Presentation","")"

```
Sub run_ppt_macro()
fName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Path = ActiveWorkbook.Path


Worksheets("PPTM").OLEObjects("PPT_Temp_19").Verb 0
Dim PPTObj As Object
Set myPP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

Set PPTObj = myPP.ActivePresentation

PPTObj.Run PPTObj.Name & "!Main", fName, Path
End Sub
```

Comment: Change PPTObj.Run to myPP.Run. Run method is available on the PowerPoint application and not on the Presentation object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Shyam, that was part of the problem.  Because the file is opened through IE or Email, it opens in a very odd place that errors the macro.  I solved the problem by saving both the data (XLSM) file and the template (PPTM) file to the temp directory, before creating the new report.

```
Sub auto_open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

fName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

tempath = IIf(Environ$("tmp") <> "", Environ$("tmp"), Environ$("temp"))    'finds the temporary evironment on the current machine
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=(tempath & "\" & fName)


MsgBox "Your report " & tempath & "\" & fName & " should be completed within 5 minutes." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Please check your PowerPoint application at that time." & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Thank you.", vbInformation


Dim PPTObj As Object
Worksheets("PPTM").OLEObjects("PPT_Temp_19").Verb 3  'opens the embedded object

Set myPP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")   'get the PowerPoint object
Set PPTObj = myPP.ActivePresentation  'Get the presentation that was opened

tempath = IIf(Environ$("tmp") <> "", Environ$("tmp"), Environ$("temp"))    'finds the temporary evironment on the current machine
Template = tempath & "\template.pptm"   'creates path and name for temp file
PPTObj.SaveAs Filename:=(Template)      'saves temp file

myPP.Presentations.Open (Template)    'opens the saved file

Worksheets("PPTM").OLEObjects("PPT_Temp_19").Object.Close


myPP.Run Template & "!Main", fName, tempath   'runs the macro

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```